# What is the best practice for storing a file upload to a MemoryStream (C#)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, memorystream

I need to temporary store a file upload to a MemoryStream.

What would be the best method to do this using asp.net (3.5)?

Here's what I have so far. It works (locally tested), but it does not look right to me.

```
protected void lnkUploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();

        BinaryWriter sWriter = new BinaryWriter(memStream);

        foreach (byte b in flUpload.FileBytes)
        {
            sWriter.Write(b);
        }

        sWriter.Flush();

        // writing to file to verify file stream converted correctly
        FileStream fstream = new FileStream(@"C:/test/" + flUpload.FileName, FileMode.Create);          
        memStream.WriteTo(fstream);         
        fstream.Dispose();

        memStream.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `flUpload.FileBytes` is a byte array, you can use the MemoryStream constructor that accepts the contained data as a parameter:

```
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(flUpload.FileBytes);
```

If not (if it just implements IEnumerable), you can convert it to a byte array using Linq:

```
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(flUpload.FileBytes.ToArray());
```

Comment: The 2nd one worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
    protected void lnkUploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(flUpload.FileBytes))
        {
            using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream(@"C:/test/" + 
                flUpload.FileName, FileMode.Create))
            {
                memStream.WriteTo(fstream);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to work with as a string... all depends on what you're going to do with it I guess.

```
System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader("path");
string file = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Or if you need the bytes there is actually a code snipet "filReadBin" you can use that produces this:

```
byte[] fileContents;
fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Test.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just three lines.

```
if (flUpload.FileName.Length > 0)
{
   string directoryPath="C:\\SomeFolderName";
   flUpload.SaveAs(directoryPath + "\\" + fileUpload.FileName);
}
```

Comment: the question was for a memorystream, not file