# ASP.NET File Upload without storing on the server

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have an ASP.NET 2 application and would like users to upload a file to be processed immediately. The file never needs to be used again, so I don't care to store it on the server as a file somewhere, which hopefully will make it more secure on our end.

Basically, they upload an excel file and I process it and display some results. I do not care to save that excel file for later.

How can I do this?

Comment: What happened to your other question, 26 minutes ago?

Answer (score 2):

You can hold the file contents in a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx).

This will ensure it is not saved to disk.

See [What is the best practice for storing a file upload to a MemoryStream (C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690337/what-is-the-best-practice-for-storing-a-file-upload-to-a-memorystream-c) for details.